# populate random data in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need help in populate some random data in my database table.
  I have a list of 10 users in my system. My allergy table has the following fields:

**id user_id name reactions status**

I have the following allergies hash in a variable called allergy_hash.

```
{:reaction_name=>"Bleeding", :status=>"Death", :name=>"A"} {:reaction_name=>"Nausea", :status=>"Serious", :name=>"B"} {:reaction_name=>"Fever", :status=>"Death", :name=>"C"} {:reaction_name=>"Blistering", :status=>"Serious", :name=>"D"}
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
def create_random_data
 users.each do |user|
   allergies.each do |allergies_hash|
     Allergy.where(user_id: user.id).first_or_create(
       allergies_hash )
     end
  end
end
```

What the above does is just inserts Bleeding, Death and A into the table for all users 1 to 10.
But I need to insert such that different users can have different values. Also some users can have more than one allergy and the associated reactions.

NOTE: I do not mean completely random. For example name 'A' should still have the associated status 'Death' and reaction_name 'Bleeding'.
Name 'B' should have the associated status 'Serious' and reaction 'Nausea'in the allergy table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the users, use `sample` on `allergies_hash = [{:reaction_name=>"Bleeding", :status=>"Death", :name=>"A"}, {:reaction_name=>"Nausea", :status=>"Serious", :name=>"B"}, {:reaction_name=>"Fever", :status=>"Death", :name=>"C"}, {:reaction_name=>"Blistering", :status=>"Serious", :name=>"D"}]`

```
Allergy.where(user_id: user.id).first_or_create(allergies_hash.sample)
```

**UPDATE**
I'll loop through the users instead, so for each user you attempt to add from 1 to 3 allergies from your allergies_hash

```
User.all.each do |user|
  [1,2,3].sample.times do
    user.allergies.where(allergies_hash.sample).first_or_create
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks.but how is the above code checking for user_id anywhere?

Comment: `user.allergies` will both search and/or add with `user_id == user.id`

Comment: is that some rails feature, how does it know the table has user_id? It could be UserId etc

Comment: I get this error: 
      undefined method `sample' for {{:reaction_name=>"Bleeding", :status=>"Death", :name=>"A"} :Hash

Comment: Sample, it's an array method, because you have an array of hashes, right?, I missed the [] in the code on my answer, do you have them?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to check [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) and [Factory girl](http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) to populate some random data.

Answer (score 0):

You can either seed data into your app by going to the seed file in the app/db directory

and do something like this

```
 User.delete_all
 Bill.delete_all

 u1 = User.create(:email => "bob@aol.com", :password =>"a", :password_confirmation => "a")

 b1 = Bill.create(:name => "rent", :description => "the rent", :amount => 10_000, :day => 1)
 b2 = Bill.create(:name => "cable", :description => "the cable", :amount => 150, :day => 5)
```

or you can also use the Faker gem to generate fake data.

http://geekswithblogs.net/alexmoore/archive/2010/01/18/faker-gem---a-quick-and-dirty-introduction.aspx

Comment: the reason i wanted to write the code is there are other functions in the code that seeds data as well. This .rake file would be run by other developers everytime they checkout a fresh copy of code. I am not supposed to add through app/db